# Python Matplotlib: labeled and stacked values in histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, histogram

relatively new python user here.
I'm trying to build a histogram of stock index annual returns.
My goal is to have a graph which looks like this:

[image: Histogram]

Can someone help me how to come up with this sort of stacked bars in the histogram with the labels for the years?
So far I have the following:

```
plt.figure()
plt.hist(returns, bins=[-0.6,-0.5,-0.4,-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7])
plt.xticks(np.arange(-0.6, 0.7, 0.1))
plt.xlabel("Returns DJIA in %")
plt.ylabel("Number of observations (Probability in %)")
```

Thanks in advance!